# How can I alloc member value with "Get" function?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, new-operator

Here's a simple code.

```
class Sub
{
    ...
public:
    Sub()
    {
        ...
    }
}

class Main
{
private:
    Sub*    m_pSub

public:

    Main()
    {
        // I don't want construct "Sub" here
        m_pSub = nullptr;
    }    

    Sub*    GetSub()
    {
        return m_pSub;
    }
}


/////////////////////
// in source
Main*   pMain;

pMain->GetSub() = new Sub()
```

Of course, **pMain->GetSub() = new Sub()** does not work because the left value of '=' in the above code must be a correctable value.

Therefore, please teach me various ways to implement similarly
(which can be used as short as possible).

Thank you !

Comment: The usual way to do this would be to provide `SetSub` method. It violates the [Law of Least Astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) to have `GetAnything` method return something through which the object can be modified. While `pMain->GetSub() = new Sub()` could be made to work, but I won't tell you how, and I don't recommend you try.

Comment: Why not `Sub* GetSub() {if (!m_pSub) m_pSub = new Sub; return m_pSub;}`?

Comment: return a reference

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I used the set function. 
`void SetSub(Sub* ptr) { m_pSub = ptr }
...
...
Sub* pSub;
pMain->SetSub(pSub);
.....`

However, I was wondering if there was a way to do it more concisely using a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to make your code work is to have `GetSub()` return a reference, eg:

```cpp
class Main
{
private:
    Sub* m_pSub = nullptr;

public:

    Main() = default;

    Sub*& GetSub()
    {
        return m_pSub;
    }
};
```

However, this isn't very good class design.

Another option is to have `GetSub()` create the object on its first call, eg:

```cpp
class Main
{
private:
    Sub* m_pSub = nullptr;

public:

    Main() = default; 

    Sub* GetSub()
    {
        if (!m_pSub) m_pSub = new Sub;
        return m_pSub;
    }
};
```

Otherwise, use an explicit setter method, eg:

```cpp
class Main
{
private:
    Sub* m_pSub = nullptr;

public:

    Main() = default;    

    Sub* GetSub()
    {
        return m_pSub;
    }

    void SetSub(Sub* newSub)
    {
        m_pSub = new Sub;
    }
};

...
pMain->SetSub(new Sub);
```

Either way, you really should be using smart pointers, either `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`, to make it clear who owns the `Sub` object and is responsible for destroying it.  A raw pointer does not convey that information.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The second method seems to be a very good method.
Then, when `delete m_pSub` is performed in the `~Main()` function, there is no need to worry about memory leaks?

Above all, the first method is similar to the answer I wanted. But is there a document that can refer to why the method is a bad code or a keyword to search for?